# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: ''automationName' can't be blank'

Tags: c#, android, appium, ui-automation

I'm getting the  ''automationName' can't be blank' error trying to create AndroidDriver. As you can see I've added the MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName but for some reason it doesn't work. Does someone get the same problems?

```
var options = new AppiumOptions();
                
options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName, AutomationName.AndroidUIAutomator2);
options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Pixel_6");
options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "path_to_app");

return new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(appiumServerUri, options);
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

fixed by changing MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName to appium:automationName
also in this case to run the app need to chage MobileCapabilityType.App to appium:app

```
var options = new AppiumOptions();
        
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:automationName",
AutomationName.AndroidUIAutomator2);
options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Pixel_6");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:app", "path_to_app");

return new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(appiumServerUri, options);
```

If you have any other suggestions how to fix, please post